# How to set a windows explorer window as the active window

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get a macro to select or activate a windows explorer window after it has completed or open the window if it is not found. Currently it does find the window handle (saved as "window") when it is open but it will not activate that window!

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _ 
    (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function BringWindowToTop Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long

Dim directory As String
directory = "C:\...\practice contracts\"

Dim directorySplit() As String
directorySplit = Split(directory, "\")

'--the rest of the macro--   

Dim window As Long
window = FindWindow("CabinetWClass", directorySplit(UBound(directorySplit) - 1))

If window <> 0 Then
    BringWindowToTop window
Else
    Shell "explorer.exe " & directory, vbNormalFocus
End If
```

I've also tried `AppActivate directorySplit(UBound(directorySplit) - 1)` instead of `FindWindow` but it also will find but not activate the window. I can tell that it finds the window and its handle because if I close the explorer window and try running `AppActivate` againt, it will raise an error instead.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Simply write `Shell "explorer.exe " & directory, vbNormalFocus` at the end, outside of any `If` etc.

Comment: That works to open a new window every time the macro is run, but I was hoping to just activate one that I already have open if possible.

Comment: From the AppActivate docs "The task ID returned by the Shell function can be used in place of title to activate an application." https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/appactivate-statement  By the way your code works for me.

Comment: @SMeaden when i call `AppActivate Shell("explorer.exe " & directory, vbNormalFocus)` I get Error 5 "Invalid procedure call or argument" and it just continues to open up new windows

Comment: Well I changed `directory = "C:\...\practice contracts\"` to something valid for me.   I presume  `...` is there to hide a sensitive directory name.

Comment: @SMeaden right, yeah

Comment: ok `Debug.Assert CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").FolderExists(directory)` should flush out syntax errors in your path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you please try this?

It worked for me in both conditions.  Just tried it again.

If it errors out on appactivate because it cannot find the window, it goes to the window open section and opens the folder.

```
On Error GoTo WindowOpen
AppActivate directorySplit(UBound(directorySplit) - 1)
Exit Sub

WindowOpen:
    Shell "explorer.exe " & directory, vbNormalFocus
```

Comment: It does run shell whenever the window is closed but unfortunately does not bring the window to the front when it is minimized/behind another window

Comment: @Ctznlane535: promising, could you bring this along a little more?

Comment: Whelp, I made a separate test module and it works... I must have done something silly the first time around

Comment: Ah okay here's something interesting - a window can be active and still be underneath other windows. So for me, I use your solution with `BringWindowToTop FindWindow("CabinetWClass", directorySplit(UBound(directorySplit) - 1))` added just above `AppActivate...`. The bit that stinks is that `BringWindowToTop` will not un-minimize a window from taskbar, so while the window is active, it's not visible

Answer (score 1):

This is another solution - simply try to close the window if it exists and then call the same window from the Shell:

```
If Window <> 0 Then Windows(Window).Close
Shell "explorer.exe " & directory, vbNormalFocus
```

It should work quite robustly and you can change the focus easily through VBA.