# Windows Explorer Opened by VBA Shell Command Not On Top

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm working with an older MS Access application in which a "Show File in Folder" function has been implemented.

This function uses this basic strategy

```
vPID = Call Shell("explorer.exe /select," & FileFullPathName, vbNormalFocus)

AppActivate vPID
```

For the most part, this works fine.  However, I have several users complaining that the window that opens is always behind other windows.  All of the users with this complaint have had their machines patched to the latest and greatest Windows 10.  I have been able to duplicated this on a similar machine.  The problem is most prevalent when there are a number of Explorer windows open a the the time the user clicks the "Show File in Folder" button.

My various searches have revealed several Windows API functions that sound like they should work (BringWindowToTop, SetForegroundWindow, SwitchToThisWindow (deprecated as far as I can tell), SetWindowPos, ShowWindow).  I think I understand the differences and the one I should be focusing on is BringWindowToTop.

I have done a number of test implementations of this, but they are best summed up by the content of this post:  [How to set a windows explorer window as the active window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48153208/how-to-set-a-windows-explorer-window-as-the-active-window).

For the time being I'm simply ignoring window cleanliness and how many windows a user might have open, etc.  If I construct the following:

'Declarations

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _ 
    (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

Private Declare Function BringWindowToTop Lib "user32" _
    (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long

'Then set the following up in a button
Dim strFile as String
dim strPath as String
dim strPathSplit() as String
dim lngWindow as Long

strFile = "C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\foo.txt"
strPath = "C:\folder1\folder2\folder3\"

strPathSplit = Split(strPath, "\")

Shell "explorer.exe /select," & strFile, vbNormalFocus

lngWindow = FindWindow("CabinetWClass", strPathSplit(UBound(strPathSplit) - 1))

BringWindowToTop lngWindow

AppActivate strPathSplit(UBound(strPathSplit) - 1)
```

I get a non-zero window handle back from FindWindow.  But the explorer window that I opened with the Shell command is stubbornly in the background.  It is flashing on the taskbar, but I still have to notice it and click it to get it on top.  (It does open correctly when I do that.)

I have tried several variants using the other Windows API functions and gotten similar results.

I would muchly appreciate it if anyone could point out what I'm doing wrong, or point me at the right technique to accomplish this.  I know it's very possible to do in other applications that have similar "Show File in Folder" functions, but I'm also aware that those were written in other languages and may have access to functions I do not.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as I noted above in one of my comments, the suggestion to pursue the identity of the process that was in the foreground did actually lead to the answer to my quandary, but not through the API functions that I was originally calling.

The answer I ended up implementing lies in SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems.  Yes, apparently it IS possible to do this VB/VBA.  There is an existing implementation of this posted by fafalone at this link:  https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?810301-VB6-Code-Snippet-Open-a-folder-and-select-multiple-files-in-Explorer.  I'll also copy the code here, but as I said, it's not mine.

His function can take string array of full paths to files and select multiple files in one folder or select files in multiple folders.  If you want to call it for a single file (like I'm doing) you just put that one file in the array.  You then call the OpenFolders subroutine with that string array.

In the following quote of fafalone's code, I have not made the modification for conditional compilation that SierraOscar pointed out as it is intended to be a direct quote, but I did actually do that in my implementation.  It does appear to make a difference.

fafalone's code is:

```
Public Type ResultFolder
    sPath As String
    sFiles() As String
End Type
Public Declare Function SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems Lib "shell32" (ByVal pidlFolder As Long, ByVal cidl As Long, ByVal apidl As Long, ByVal dwFlags As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function ILCreateFromPathW Lib "shell32" (ByVal pwszPath As Long) As Long
Public Declare Function ILFindLastID Lib "shell32" (ByVal pidl As Long) As Long
Public Declare Sub CoTaskMemFree Lib "ole32.dll" (ByVal pv As Long)

Public Sub OpenFolders(sFiles() As String)

If sFiles(0) = "" Then Exit Sub 'caller is responsible for ensuring array has been dim'd and contains valid info

Dim tRes() As ResultFolder
Dim apidl() As Long
Dim ppidl As Long
Dim pidlFQ() As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long

GetResultsByFolder sFiles, tRes

'Now each entry in tRes is a folder, and its .sFiles member contains every file
'in the original list that is in that folder. So for every folder, we now need to
'create a pidl for the folder itself, and an array of all the relative pidls for the 
'files. Two helper APIs replace what used to be tons of pidl-related support
'code before XP. After we've got the pidls, they're handed off to the API
For i = 0 To UBound(tRes)
    ReDim apidl(UBound(tRes(i).sFiles))
    ReDim pidlFQ(UBound(tRes(i).sFiles))
    For j = 0 To UBound(tRes(i).sFiles)
        pidlFQ(j) = ILCreateFromPathW(StrPtr(tRes(i).sFiles(j))) 'ILCreateFromPathW gives us Unicode support
        apidl(j) = ILFindLastID(pidlFQ(j))
    Next
    ppidl = ILCreateFromPathW(StrPtr(tRes(i).sPath))

    Call SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems(ppidl, UBound(apidl) + 1, VarPtr(apidl(0)), 0&) 
    'Vista+ has dwFlags to start renaming (single file) or select on desktop; there's no valid flags on XP

    'now we need to free all the pidls we created, otherwise it's a memory leak
    CoTaskMemFree ppidl
    For j = 0 To UBound(pidlFQ)
        CoTaskMemFree pidlFQ(j) 'per MSDN, child ids obtained w/ ILFindLastID don't need ILFree, so just free FQ
    Next
Next
        
End Sub

Private Sub GetResultsByFolder(sSelFullPath() As String, tResFolders() As ResultFolder)
Dim i As Long
Dim sPar As String
Dim k As Long, cn As Long, fc As Long
ReDim tResFolders(0)

For i = 0 To UBound(sSelFullPath)
    sPar = Left$(sSelFullPath(i), InStrRev(sSelFullPath(i), "\") - 1)
    k = RFExists(sPar, tResFolders)
    If k >= 0 Then 'there's already a file in this folder, so just add a new file to the folders list
        cn = UBound(tResFolders(k).sFiles)
        cn = cn + 1
        ReDim Preserve tResFolders(k).sFiles(cn)
        tResFolders(k).sFiles(cn) = sSelFullPath(i)
    Else 'create a new folder entry
        ReDim Preserve tResFolders(fc)
        ReDim tResFolders(fc).sFiles(0)
        tResFolders(fc).sPath = sPar
        tResFolders(fc).sFiles(0) = sSelFullPath(i)
        fc = fc + 1
    End If
Next
End Sub

Private Function RFExists(sPath As String, tResFolders() As ResultFolder) As Long
Dim i As Long
For i = 0 To UBound(tResFolders)
    If tResFolders(i).sPath = sPath Then
        RFExists = i
        Exit Function
    End If
Next
RFExists = -1
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You aren't checking the return value from BringWindowToTop. You should do that.
If you check the return value from (some of the) function, it will tell you that the attempt failed.

The flashing taskbar indicates that the Window was correctly notified, but can't be brought do the top because *some other window* won't let it come up.

**Nothing you do to the file dialog window will bring it to the top** -- the problem is that it's not attached to the active process.

Conditions for success are described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setforegroundwindow

If Office / Win10 has been re-engineered to have this behavior, a solution will be to find the handle of the process which has the foreground, and use that to create the new dialog, or use it to release focus and push it to the background, because two processes trying to be in the foreground at the same time doesn't work.

In the past this was often caused by the user clicking twice when only once was required -- grabbing focus. You should check that isn't happening.

Comment: thanks for this!  I suspect that you're correct about where the solution lies.  However, it appears to be a rabbit hole down which I went.  I never did find the "bottom" of that hole, but I did find a solution in implementation of SHOpenFolderAndSelectItems, which seems to be the "Easy Button" for this in the various C languages.  Implementation in VB is slightly byzantine but understandable.  See below.

Answer (score 0):

You should use conditional compilation to check which version of Windows you're on and change your declarations appropriately. 32bit Windows handles `Long` types differently to 64bit:

```
#If Win64 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" _
               (ByVal hWnd As LongPtr) As LongPtr
#Else
    Private Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" _
               (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
#End If

Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _ 
        (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
```

Then seeing as you already have the window handle you can just use:

```
SetForegroundWindow lngWindow
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Using SetForegroundWindow was on the list of things I'd tried already, but I was willing to give the conditional declarations a go (as I couldn't remember if I'd tried that or not.)  Unfortunately the results are essentially the same.  The difference being that if I invoke the "Show File in Folder" function twice, the second time it does move both windows the front.  However, if I only do it one time the explorer window stays behind.